# Opening a text in notepad in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, shellexecute, cfiledialog, cfile

Just as the title stated. How do I open a text in notepad in MFC?

I used the `CFileDialog` to open up a "Save As" dialog box like so :

```
TCHAR szFilters[] = 
    _T ("Text files (*.txt)¦*.txt¦All files (*.*)¦*.*¦¦");

CFileDialog dlg (FALSE, _T ("txt"), _T ("*.txt"),
    OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT, szFilters);

if (dlg.DoModal () == IDOK)
    m_strPathName = dlg.GetPathName();
```

After I have the path name in `m_strPathName`, is there anyway to directly open up the txt file that had been saved in a Notepad?

I have another button `OnShowData` and this is the code inside.

`ShellExecute(NULL, _T("open"), m_strPathName, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);`

Is there any other method that I could do this??

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

Comment: What's wrong with that way? If you want more control, there's `CreateProcess`.

Comment: @chris any example on this??

Comment: Tons. The Internet is your beach. Google is your metal detector.

Comment: Of course the difference is that the way you have now assumes Notepad is the associated program (if there is one) for .txt files.

Comment: Ok. Sorry for asking such a stupid question. Found my answer...

Answer (score 0):

The following API can also be used for the same

WinExec("C:\MyFolder", ...)

Comment: WinExec is decprecated. Stick with ShellExecute or ShellExecuteEx.